# Extract section contents from HTML using perl

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I want to get all contents of a section tag in an HTML string using perl. I'm using the following line of code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$article_content =~ s/^.*?<section>(.*)<\/section>.*?$/$1/;
```

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: @jordanm Obligatory response: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Very educational.

Comment: @Cyborgx37 I believe that particular post by tchrist contains a certain amount of irony.

Comment: @TLP - Perhaps, but in my experience it is more effective to say "That way is possible, but extremely difficult. This way is much simpler." then to say "Don't do it that way. Do it this way. This way is better for reasons you can't understand."

Comment: @Cyborgx37 Either way, it seems clear that the general recommendation is to not write your own regexes.

Answer (score 1):

Change `(.*)` to `(.*?)` and see if that helps.

Comment: Note, however, that this will not work perfectly in all scenarios. E.g. `<section>abc<!--</section>-->xyz</section>`

Comment: And, yes my approach will not work given @Cyborgx37 example. But since our company is also generating the content, this shouldn't happen (I hope...)

Comment: So what ends up in the capture group for the two variants? i.e., (.*) and (.*?)

Comment: For this case, after I added the /s option, it's the same. If I understand correctly, (.*?) is the non-greedy way and since there is only one <section> tag in our htmls, (.*) and (.*?) has the same result...

Comment: True, now that I know that you only have one <section>.  However, for the kind of match (i'm not talking about whether you are working with HTML or not) you are trying to do, you should develop judicious use of (.*?) as a habit.  When you know something before and after the group you are trying to match, you almost always want non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl.html for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules.

Comment: This is not exactly right. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/211627. The correct response should be: "Parsing HTML with regexes is the hard way. Consider something easier, like XYZ."

Comment: It's close enough for beginners.  Tom Christiansen knows the rules so it's OK for him to break them.  OP does not.

Comment: As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, it will likely break your code no matter how you extract data from the HTML.

Comment: What I'm talking about is that OP's code that looks for `<section>` will break if that every becomes `<section >` or `<section id="foo">`, which are perfectly valid and should not change the behavior of his program.

Comment: Engineers are fascinated with "unsolvable" problems. Tell me that something can't be done, and I'll instinctively try to prove you wrong. But show me that something is extremely difficult with little reward, and I'll follow you anywhere for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is that you assume `.` matches any character, but that's only the case when using `/s`.